# List View Item row click Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing a Cart App in which i need to open that particular item in an activity, which has been clicked by the user in List View.

I am using two different activities, one to show selected Item(s) in a List View namely **CartActivity.java** and second to show any of the selected item in another activity namely **ProductInformationActivity.java**

I have written code to call that particular item in an activity, which has been selected by user, in a List View of *CartActivity.java*

```
    // below is the line number 77

    itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
```

Logcat Says:

```
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.era.restaurant.versionoct/com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:287)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.onCreate(ProductInformationActivity.java:77)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is your line number 77 `04-30 14:37:10.073: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.era.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity.onCreate(ProductInformationActivity.java:77)`

Comment: Start by looking at ProductInformationActivity.java line 77

Comment: May be due to text should be null or txt_total.setText(String.valueOf(itemamount));

Comment: @SilentKiller like i posted and written above, line number 77 is: itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse a String into a Double. The string is coming from:

```
text_cost_code.getText()
```

So if text_cost_code is not a number, you get this exception. Make sure that the textView holds a correct formatted number.

Comment: i posted more code of ProductInformationActivity.java, check now

Comment: You need to surround the statement within try/catch. See the answer from ling.s.

Answer (score 1):

`Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());` throws a `NumberFormatException` because `Double.parseDouble()` can't handle strings that don't fit its expected format. Check if `text_cost_code.getText()` contains a number.

Comment: i posted more code of ProductInformationActivity.java, check now

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
try {
 itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString()); // Same
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  itemamount=0.0;
 // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error: Edittext must contain numbers " ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
txt_total.setText(String.valueOf(itemamount));
```

As per your edit

```
if (!edit_qty_code.getText().toString().equals("")
                || !edit_qty_code.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

Here, you only checks whether the `dit_qty_code` is empty or not, you didn't check whether it contain numbers

Comment: i posted more code of ProductInformationActivity.java, check now

Comment: see my edited answer, see the code carefully txt_total.setText(String.valueOf(itemamount));

Answer (score 0):

Use **validation** before TypeCasting the value directly from TextView or EditText

```
    if (text_cost_code.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
    } else {
        itemamount = 0;
    }
```

before doing this you must keep a validation of `android:inputtype="number"` in xml code for this EditText so user won't allow to add except numericals... :)

Comment: @ling.s it is common sense that if the EditText is named as Cost code so cost must have `inputType as number` so it won't allow alphabets..